# Header Files for Running "parsefmt" in C?

Tags: c, parsing, system, header-files, tty

Recently I came across the code for the "ps" Linux command which utilizes a "parsefmt" function to get information such as the PID, tty, and path. However, I am at a loss for how to use the function; I have included all the header functions from the actual ps.c file (https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158/ps/ps.c.auto.html) and I am still getting the error:

```
implicit declaration of function 'parsefmt' is invalid in C99
```

If anyone could guide me on how to use this function, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s defined in [keyword.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158/ps/keyword.c.auto.html) in the same directory and the prototype is in [extern.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158/ps/extern.h.auto.html)

Comment: You are definitely correct; however, when I try to include "extern.h" in my C file, I am getting "fatal error: 'extern.h' file not found". People have recommended using Perl to get past this problem, but I have installed perl ("brew install perl") and am still getting the "file not found" error for extern.h. Any advice?

Comment: You’ll have to download the files from the Apple open source site.

Comment: I found the files on the openbsd github, but the file (https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/bin/ls/extern.h) doesn't have "parsefmt" anymore for some reason... Where do you download files on the Apple Open Source site?

Comment: If you're going to be successful as a programmer, you're really going to have to get better at finding things. You know the site the files are on, you have links to the files and with all that information and google you could not come up with https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158.tar.gz